# How can I write looping data matrix into same excel file?

Tags: excel, matlab, export

I have a looping data matrix in matlab, and I want to write it into same excel file. If I use the xlswrite('name.xls', M) it'll make a 'name.xls' excel, contained one matrix (value of the last looping). How can I write all my looping matrix (lets say it has 10 matrix with 13 columns) in one file excel and that excel file will contain all my matrix with 13 columns (so there'll be 10 rows with 13 columns). Please help, Thanks. -Machmum

Comment: What does your data look like, can you combine all the data into one matrix?

Answer (score 1):

In each loop iteration add your newest vector to a single matrix. Then only after the loop, write this matrix to a .xls file:

```
M = zeros(10,13);  %// Pre-allocation like this is essential for speed
for k = 1:10
    ... %Your code
    M(k,:) = ... %//Put your new 1-by-13 vector that you create each iteration here
end

xlswrite(file_name, M)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be better to create the matrix first and then write it in one go as Dan has suggested, it is possible to specify where `xlswrite` starts writing, which allows you to append data to existing files.  If only specifying a start location, you must also give `xlswrite` a sheet name.  This will be slower than pre-calculating the matrix and then just calling `xlswrite` once, though.

Simple example:

```
M = 1:10;

for n = 1:10

    t = sprintf('A%d',n); % starting cell A1 through A10
    xlswrite('testdata.xls',M*n,'Sheet1',t);  % writes one row 

end
```